# How to implement Elastic Search with Django rest framework without using viewsets?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I want to design a search system using Django rest framework and Elastic Search. I could not get a proper tutorial on what each of the things mentioned in `elasticsearch-dsl` and `elasticsearch-dsl-drf` stand and how to use them with full explanation. Any guides and suggestions would be very highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you define "implement Elastic Search with Django rest framework"? What is your goal?

Comment: I want to make a search engine functionality to search products from database, matching price, categories, name, id etc.